# Infinispan Clustering: Replication of entries loaded by a CacheLoader

Tags: java, infinispan

*Sorry, wall of text; there's a summary at the bottom.*

I am prototyping a Java application that will run on multiple servers. Every instance has an embedded Infinispan cache and the caches are configured to form a cluster in replication mode. The cache entries are loaded from an external system only - there is no need for actively adding entries using `cache.put(key, value)`.

For that purpose, I implemented a custom CacheLoader. Loading values on-demand is working, but these entries are not replicated to other active cluster nodes. For test reasons, I tried adding entries with 'put' - these are replicated immediately.

The user guide pointed me to properties that affect cluster behavior when nodes are joining/leaving the cluster, or during writes, like *fetchPersistentState*, *shared* and *fetchInMemoryState*. The latter is useful in my case, since new nodes joining the cluster should receive the current state. And this initial synchronzation during startup is even fetching the entries loaded by the cache loader.

*fetchPersistentState* caused errors because my cache loader does not implement AdvancedCacheLoader - but since the advanced methods do not seem to be called after an invocation of 'load' I do not think that correctly implementing that interface would solve my problem.

I have also read about the ClusterLoader implementation that

> consults other members in the cluster for values

but a roundtrip to the other nodes would increase response times while processing requests.

The rationale behind trying to load the value exactly once is that calls to the shared external system are considered to be rather expensive, so that the increased cluster-overhead created by replication messages should still be less problematic than loading the values on every node.

In order to have some kind of isolated test and code samples for this I forked the *infinispan-quickstart/clustered-cache* example on Github and adapted it to my needs:

https://github.com/flpa/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/clustered-cache

The cache is backed by a CacheLoader now and nodes are periodically fetching/putting values to demonstrate how 'put' values are replicated but values fetched from the loader are not.

**To sum this up:**

Is it possible to configure an Infinispan cluster in replication mode that is populated entirely by cache loader lookups and replicates the results of those lookups on all nodes?

**EDIT: I accidentally deleted the Github fork, so I recreated it from scratch including only the relevant 'clustered-cache' folder and adapted the link above.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that out-of-the-box configuration options are not available. However, you can register listener on each node for the `@CacheEntryLoaded` event and in this listener execute `putAsync()`. Be sure to include flags `SKIP_CACHE_LOAD`, `SKIP_CACHE_STORE` and `IGNORE_RETURN_VALUES` to get the best performance.

Comment: Thanks Flavius, I implemented this solution in my test app and it's working. It'll probably take some time until I can test this in a real-life environment but I'll just accept the answer right away.